# How to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, junit

One of my test cases is  getting `NoSuchMethodError`.  I've removed `getExceptionHandler()` method from the project so this method shouldn't be detected at all. This is the only test case with this error.

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: mig.eis.common.service.impl.iso.ISOPPCServiceHelper.getExceptionHandler()Lmig/eis/framework/exception/IExceptionHandler;
at mig.eis.common.service.impl.iso.ISOPPCServiceHelper.mergePPCInputTemplate(ISOPPCServiceHelper.java:62)
at mig.eis.common.service.impl.iso.ISOServiceDelegate.retrieveData(ISOServiceDelegate.java:36)
at mig.eis.provider.thirdparty.ISOPPCLookupProvider.retrieveData(ISOPPCLookupProvider.java:40)
at test.mig.eis.provider.thirdparty.TestISOPPCLookupProvider.test(TestISOPPCLookupProvider.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I don't know how to tell the compiler that `getExceptionHandler()` doesn't exist any more.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your test! The test calls `ISOPPCServiceHelper` which still uses the method `getExceptionHandler()`. You have to recompile that class. Always use clean test of your build system after refactorings to make sure everything is compiled right (hopefully you have one, otherwise rebuild project of your IDE should do the job).

Comment: I did clean and build but still I am getting the same error and the strange thing is that why only this particular class shows that it has this method.

Comment: How is your project structure? Do you have multiple modules or even projects? Is there a snapshot dependency between them? How is your project built?

Comment: I got multiple projects that depend on each other. Usually I do clean and build for entire work space and that usually take care of everything.

Comment: It worked now. I had to recompile that project using Maven and it started picking up the latest code. Thanks Arne.